# Why do I get a 403 error when trying to start Grails 3.1.12?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to run Grails 3.1.12 on Mac OSX (10.11.5).

`grails -version` gives me the following output:

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.12
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_71
```

And then if I run `grails --stacktrace --verbose` I get this:

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Forbidden (403)
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden (403)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.handleStatus(HttpTransporter.java:466)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:291)
at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:243)
at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:302)
at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:284)
at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:276)
at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:53)
at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:49)
at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.<init>(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:56)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.createMavenProfileRepository(GrailsCli.groovy:329)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:238)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:163)
```

I can't even create a project or simply start Grails in interactive mode. I don't have any `GRAILS_OPTS` set. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Aether is the dependency library from Maven that Grails use for jar and plugin dependencies, so you must have something misconfigured that's affecting your ability to resolve jar files.

Comment: e.g. corporate proxy, ...

Comment: I don't have any proxy setup, I'm just trying to run it at home, regular Internet. I've uninstalled all other Grails versions I had and got the same results. How do I figure out what could be wrong with Aether? Any ideas @BurtBeckwith? I honestly don't even know where to start, as the stacktrace doesn't say much about my setup.